# Simple changing of innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript

I have this code, I want to click on the Link that's in the `<span>` and then that should change the innerHTML of exactly this `<span>`.

```
<span id="button_report_<?php echo $row->id ?>_spam"><a class="btn red btn-xs" onlick="changeSpamButton<?php echo $row->id ?>()" target="report_iframe_<?php echo $row->id ?>" href="resource/report.php?id=<?php echo $row->id ?>&ttype=currency&type=spam">Spam</a></span>
<span id="button_report_<?php echo $row->id ?>_na"><a class="btn yellow btn-xs" onlick="changeNAButton<?php echo $row->id ?>()" target="report_iframe_<?php echo $row->id ?>" href="resource/report.php?id=<?php echo $row->id ?>&ttype=currency&type=na">Unavailability</a></span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeSpamButton<?php echo $row->id ?>() {
    document.getElementById("button_report_<?php echo $row->id ?>_spam").innerHTML = '<a class="btn default btn-xs">Spam</a>';
}

function changeNAButton<?php echo $row->id ?>() {
    document.getElementById("button_report_<?php echo $row->id ?>_na").innerHTML = '<a class="btn default btn-xs">Unavailability</a>';
}
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `onlick -> onclick`. There is no "lick" event in the DOM. However, instead of creating functions for each element, you can do this a lot simpler (maybe someone else will provide a nice solution ;)). I encourage you to read the [excellent articles about event handling on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html). They also explain the event object and which information you have access to inside the event handler (for example, it's unnecessary to call `document.getElementById` to get a reference to the element you bound the handler to).

Comment: Oh well, must've been something like that. Thanks a lot! Yeah, probably, I have very little knowledge about javascript so that's fine for me :-P Thanks for the article!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said, you'd have to change `onlick` to `onclick`. But to give you an idea how to simplify the event handling:

```
<span data-type="spam">
    <a onclick="changeButton(this.parentNode)">Spam</a>
</span>
<span data-type="na">
    <a onclick="changeButton(this.parentNode)">Unavailability</a>
</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
var content = {
    'spam': '<a class="btn default btn-xs">Spam</a>',
    'na': '<a class="btn default btn-xs">Unavailability</a>'
};

function changeButton(element) {
   element.innerHTML = content[element.getAttribute('data-type')];
}
</script>
```

This makes your code easier to read, understand and maintain.

Reading material: [Introduction to event handling - quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I appreciate it, that's perfect.